# Memory error when resizing input image using tf.image.resize()

Tags: tensorflow, memory, resize, conv-neural-network

I have an input image of `(100,100,1)` and I want resize the image to `(64,64,1)`
I'm getting memory error each time,
it worth noting that my data set contain 58366 images.
Any solution ?

Comment: I think you need to add it some code for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` to resize images more efficiently.

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory, labels='inferred', label_mode='int',
    class_names=None, color_mode='rgb', batch_size=32, image_size=(64,
    64), shuffle=True, seed=None, validation_split=None, subset=None,
    interpolation='bilinear', follow_links=False, smart_resize=False
)
```

Calling image_dataset_from_directory(main_directory, labels='inferred') will return a `tf.data.Dataset` that yields batches of images from the subdirectories `class_a` and `class_b`, together with labels 0 and 1 (0 corresponding to class_a and 1 corresponding to class_b)